# If function $f$ has zero value and positive derivative at both endpoints, then $f''(\eta)=f(\eta)$ for some $\eta$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, twice differentiable in $(a,b)$.
Given that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, $f'(a)f'(b) > 0$,
Prove that $\exists \zeta \in (a,b), f(\zeta) = 0$ and $\exists \eta \in (a,b),f''(\eta) = f(\eta)$.

I solved the former part. For the latter part, I found a counter example.
$f(x) = \sin x$ in $(0,\pi)$, there is no $\eta \in (0,\pi)$ s.t. $f''(\eta) = f(\eta)$

If the the statement becomes $\exists \eta \in [a,b],f''(\eta) = f(\eta)$.
Is it true?

Comment: $f'(0)\cdot f'(\pi)$ is negative for your $f$.

Comment: oops, my mistake. so the original question is correct...

Comment: The linked question in previous comment has a very nice and short answer based on concept of maxima/minima.

Answer (score 2):

Put $h(x)=f^{\prime\prime}(x)-f(x)$, and suppose that $h(x)\not =0$ on $(a,b)$. Put $g(x)=f^{\prime}(x)+f(x)$. We have $g^{\prime}(x)-g(x)=h(x)$, hence if $A(x)=g(x)\exp(-x)$, ,we get $A^{\prime}(x)=h(x)\exp(-x)$. As $h(x)\not =0$ on $(a,b)$, we have $A^{\prime}(x)\not =0$ on $(a,b)$. By Darboux's theorem, $A^{\prime}$ has a constant sign on $(a,b)$ (and then $h$ also has a constant sign on $(a,b)$), wlog suppose $A^{\prime}(x)>0$ hence $A$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$. We have hence $A(a)\leq A(x)\leq A(b)$ or $A(b)\leq A(x)\leq A(a)$. But $A(a)A(b)=f^{\prime}(a)f^{\prime}(b)\exp(-a-b)>0$. Hence $A$ has a constant sign on $[a,b]$, so this is true also for $g$. Now $g(x)\exp(x)=(f(x)\exp(x))^{\prime}$, and $f(x)\exp(x)$ is strictly monotonic on $[a,b]$. As $f(a)=f(b)=0$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: @David Mitra: OK, I edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Nice trick on setting A(x)!